# Isolation forest parameters

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, data

I am implementing Isolation Forest from scratch, I am in dilemma of how to set contamination value, and what if not used im the code. Is accuracy differ? What other parameters required to run correctly. 
I am using only 5 fold cross validation, then drawing forest, then computing tye amomaly scores and if <=0.5 then Normal otherwise Anomaly. Is it correct?

Comment: Thanks for your post. May I ask you kindly to have a look at related post [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/90720/incorrect-results-of-isolationforest)?